# Send json array of dictionaries from swift 3 to php

Tags: php, json, swift, dictionary, nsurlconnection

I want to send an array of dictionaries to a php file using NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest. i thought the best way to do so is to send a json object to the php file in order to avoid sending each object on its own. however, the json object is being sent successfully and received by the php file but when i decode the object I get null instead. Anyone knows whats wrong with my code?

my swift code is:

```
var jsonArray = [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()


    for user in users {

        let dictionary = ["user_id": user.userid, "username":user.username] as [String : Any] // random example

        jsonArray.append(dictionary as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
    }

    let url: URL = URL(string: str)!

    let rqst:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url)

    rqst.timeoutInterval = 10

    let bodyData = "json=\(jsonArray)"

    rqst.httpMethod = "POST"

    rqst.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    rqst.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

php side:

```
if(isset($_POST["json"])){

    echo "hello world";
    $json = $_POST["json"];

    echo $json;

    $jsonArray = json_decode($json);

    echo gettype($jsonArray);
}

else
    echo "missing fields";
```

what's happening is that when i echo the type of the jsonArray i get null even though when i echo $json i get the correct value. 
Also, adding `rqst.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` to my swift code makes $_POST["json"]not set.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're actually sending the `description` value of a `Dictionary` structure that is a little bit different than `JSON`.

Dictionary has `=` instead of `:` for example. You should rewrite your dictionary in a valid JSON string.

First, convert your `Dictionary` instance in a `NSData` instance by using `NSJSONSerialization` object

```
let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: .AllowFragments)
```

And then convert the `NSData` in a `String`

```
let json = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Now you can send this `json` value in your request.

Comment: i am sending an array of dictionaries though, do i do the data = NSJSONSerialization to each dictionary or to the array of dictionaries in the end?

Comment: You can convert directly your array

Comment: i did as you said and now it echoes for the $json object the number of bytes instead of the actual object and the json_decode($json) still returns null

Comment: Are you converting the `NSData` value in a `String` as I said?

Comment: yes and now it worked but the php is receiving the json structure with : and not = so i can't loop over the array since its giving me each member of the array is an object not a dictionary, how do i fix that ?

Comment: Your dictionary should be considered as a bi-dimensional array in PHP. Check your structure by printing the `json_decode` result

Comment: its an array of objects instead of array of dictionaries